# Intersystems Caché CSP DIRECTORY_ROOT

Tags: intersystems-cache

Is there any method or property to get string like PHP's $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ?
I am searching through Caché Class Documentation without success.
Many thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what are you trying to achieve, and at which moment. If you need this during web request, so, it will be available through variable `%request` which is an instance of [%CSP.Request](https://cedocs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?APP=1&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25CSP.Request). Where available a few CgiEnvs, one of them is PATH_TRANSLATED, which has a translated full path on a filesystem to the requested page. `%request.GetCgiEnv("PATH_TRANSLATED")`

If you need the root of CSP folders from anywhere you can use this code

```
set cspdir = ##class(%File).NormalizeDirectory(##class(%File).SubDirectoryName($System.Util.DataDirectory(),"csp"))
```